# jQuery Innerfade - fading weirdly on IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, fadein, fadeout

I'm wrapping up a new site, http://architect.sitesbyjoe.com and I'm using the innerfade plugin on the site's homepage. For some reason, the fading is slow and choppy.

The only other thing JavaScript-wise is the Fancy Zoom, but I've already removed it etc with no change.

Any thoughts? Other posts are pointing to CSS issues....

Comment: Ok, I'm continuing to look into this and I'm now sure it's my screen.css file. More to come.

Comment: Solved my own issue!  There were couple "position:absolute"'s that seemed to be causing the choppiness. Weird!

I replaced all I could with some floats etc and everything is working nicely.

Comment: Your site looks awesome, congratulations.

Comment: Just one other word of caution - the IE javascript engine is by far the slowest of the major browsers. This is often why you see bad clientside performance in IE, but not Chrome, FF, Opera, etc. The upside of this I guess is that IE will help identify performance issues very easily since it tends to crap out before FF, etc. lol.. Nice Site btw..

Comment: You should put your solution in as an answer and accept it as answer so this moves from the unanswered list perhaps?

Comment: Agreed that you should mark this as answered.

One other thing I've experienced before, too, was that when there were a lot of fading items to cycle through, it was more likely to get choppy.  It seems to have improved (either browser support or jQuery & innerfade) but if you run into it again, that may be playing a part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a combination of floating and absolute positioning.  I removed one of the two and things started behaving again!

Answer (score 2):

I can't help myself, I still wonder - isn't that innerfade tad overkill? (I noticed you use it only for the landing page, don't you?)

I did the very same with like 20 lines of jQuery code (and it's a bit configurable :) ) - if you're interested, I could post it :)

Also, the animation still feels a bit choppy in Google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I opened your main page in FF with firebug extension, enabled the console.  It is throwing this error about as fast as it can scroll:

this.GetObj(this.divID) is null
https://server.iad.liveperson.net/hcp/html/mTag.js?site=61775231
Line 1

this.GetObj(this.divID) is null
https://server.iad.liveperson.net/hcp/html/mTag.js?site=61775231
Line 1

Maybe that function is eating away at your cpu cycles?